# Integration step

Tags: integration

How to calculate the integral of
$\frac{4t}{(16-t^2)^2}$?

A solution manual says it should be $\frac{4}{2(16-t^2)}$ but I'm not understandig this step. Is there somebody who could explain it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could solve this using the substitution $u=16-t^2$ thus giving $\text{d}u=-2t \text{ d}t$

The original integral can be arranged into this form:
$$ \int \frac{4t\text{ d}t}{(16-t^2)^2} = -2\int \frac{-2t\text{ d}t}{(16-t^2)^2}$$
thus after making the substitution for $u$ and $\text{d}u$ gives:
$$ -2\int \frac{\text{ d}u}{u^2}=-2[-\frac{1}{u}]=\frac{2}{u} \text{ replacing $u$ again gives the answer to be: } \frac{2}{16-t^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Make a substitution $u=16-t^2$, $du=-2t$ and then try.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Make the substitution $t^2=u$